# Scraping Data from AngularJS loaded page

Tags: angularjs, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from a public site [PINNACLE](https://www.pinnacle.com/en/odds/match/basketball/usa/nba?sport=True) page.

The page contains a div which when I fetch from Apps Script shows empty. I understand that it is because the data is loaded over ajax after page is loaded.
[image]
On checking the page, I came to know that they using AngularJS. **I checked using Chrome Developer Tools but could not find the ajax URL for the same.
Could anyone help me on this**. I need to fetch the data shown in table below using Google Apps Script.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for looking into it.
I figured out the URL as shown in below image. The URL is https://www.pinnacle.com/webapi/1.17/api/v1/GuestLines/Deadball/4/487?callback=angular.callbacks._0
[image]