# Cheerio selector doesn't select some elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, cheerio, request-promise

I am trying to build a module that does some basic scraping on an official NBA box score page (e.g. https://stats.nba.com/game/0021800083) using request-promise and cheerio. I wrote the following test code:

```
const rp = require("request-promise");
const co = require("cheerio");

// the object to be exported
var stats = {};

const test = (gameId) => {
  rp(`http://stats.nba.com/game/${gameId}`)
    .then(response => {
      const $ = co.load(response);

      $('td.player').each((i, element) => {
        console.log(element);
      });

  });
};

// TESTING
test("0021800083");

module.exports = stats;
```

When I inspect the test webpage, there are multiple instances of `td` tags with `class="player"`, but for some reason selecting them with cheerio doesn't work.

But cheerio does successfully select some elements, including `a`, `script` and `div` tags.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a scraper like request-promise will not work for a site built with AngularJS. Your response does not consist of the rendered HTML, as you are probably expecting. You can confirm by console logging the response. In order to properly scrape this site you could use PhantomJS, Selenium Webdriver, and the like.

An easier approach is to identify the AJAX call that is providing the data your are after and scrape that instead. For this, go to the site and in the developer tools, open the Network tab. Look at the list of requests and identify which one has the data you are after.

Assuming you are after the player stats in the tables, the one I believe you are looking for is "0021800083_gamedetail.json"

Further reading:
[Can you scrape a Angular JS website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124491/can-you-scrape-a-angular-js-website)
[Scraping Data from AngularJS loaded page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983160/scraping-data-from-angularjs-loaded-page)

Best of luck!

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the response!